# I'm not understanding the password_hash() function

Tags: php, hash, passwords, password-encryption

I've just learned that PHP has a `password_hash()` function, instead of manually calling a hashing algorithm on a password. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

But I have two questions about the documentation.

1. The first one is about the default hashing algorithm, using `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` as the algorithm. Since PHP 5.5 the algorithm is `bcrypt`, and then it says:

> Note that this constant is designed to change over time as new and
>   stronger algorithms are added to PHP. For that reason, the length of
>   the result from using this identifier can change over time. Therefore,
>   it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can
>   expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice)

How am I supposed to still keep users being able to log in after a hashing algorithm changes, if I'm only keeping the result of a hash, and the result of the password hash will become different?

2. Under the `salt` option it says:

> Warning The salt option has been deprecated as of PHP 7.0.0. It is now
>   preferred to simply use the salt that is generated by default.

If the function will generate a salt, then wouldn't the resulting hash be different in two different executions for the same password? Unless the algorithm for generating salts is such that the same password would always get the same salt, but that would defeat the purpose of using salt, wouldn't it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can bcrypt have built-in salts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832445/how-can-bcrypt-have-built-in-salts)

Answer (score 1):

> How am I supposed to still keep users being able to log in after a hashing algorithm changes, if I'm only keeping the result of a hash, and the result of the password hash will become different?
>
> If the function will generate a salt, then wouldn't the resulting hash be different in two different executions for the same password?

The [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) function will detect the hash (and salt) used to hash a specific password and act accordingly.

Use that function to check whether the password input by a user is correct.

Comment: Oh now I get it.... What about the changing algorithm part tho? If I start using this with the `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` argument, but then the default algorithm changes in the next version, my users won't be able to log in anymore because the compared hash will be incorrect?

Comment: @ImNotMike No, it'll still work. The algorithm used is recorded in the hash, along with the configuration and salt.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I meant tho. Like, if you sign up for my site, and I store your password hash today, then tomorrow I upgrade PHP and thus the password_hash algorithm changes, will you still be able to log in? All I have stored is your (old) password hash. But tomorrow when the hash process upon logging in executes, the resulting hash of the password you have entered will be different than the password hash I have stored in the database for you, even tho the entered password is the same.

Comment: @ImNotMike Yes. Again, `password_verify()` takes care of this. It reads information that is stored in the hash about what hashing algorithm and salt was used, and repeats that process on the input password.

Comment: @ImNotMike - This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20399775/575765) describes the format of the stored hash, so may be it can clear it up.

Answer (score 0):

> How am I supposed to still keep users being able to log in after a hashing algorithm changes, if I'm only keeping the result of a hash, and the result of the password hash will become different?

The [`password_hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) documentation currently gives the following example:

```php
echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

This produces output that looks like

> $2y$10$.vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD98HNOgsNpDczlqm3Jq7KnEd1rVAGv3Fykk1a

When you call [`password_verify`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php), you call it like

```php
password_verify('rasmuslerdorf', '$2y$10$.vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD98HNOgsNpDczlqm3Jq7KnEd1rVAGv3Fykk1a')
```

Note that this does not have parameters for the algorithm or options.  Why?  Because they are stored in that output.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Algorithm | 2y |
| Cost | 10 |
| Salt | .vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD98HNO |
| Actual hash | gsNpDczlqm3Jq7KnEd1rVAGv3Fykk1a |

In other words, `password_verify` does not get the algorithm from what your program is currently using.  It gets it from what is stored in the database.  So even if you change the algorithm, it will still use the old algorithm to verify the hash.  The actual recommended way to do password verification is something like

```php
if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
  if (password_needs_rehash($hash, $algo, $options)) {
    $user->set_hash(password_hash($password, $algo, $options));
  }

  return true;
}

return false;
```

This will update the hash at login whenever it is out of date.  The `$user->set_hash` method would save the new hash to the database (you have to implement this; the password_ functions are part of PHP).  The `$password` is the plain text version just entered by the user.  The `$hash` is the hash previously stored.

You can read more about this at [`password_needs_rehash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-needs-rehash.php) in the PHP documentation.

> If the function will generate a salt, then wouldn't the resulting hash be different in two different executions for the same password?

It would, but you don't call `password_hash` to verify the password.  Instead, you call `password_verify`.  The `password_verify` function does not generate a salt.  It uses the one from the hash.

You might then ask why use a salt?  This is covered extensively in other questions' answers (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6832445/6660678)), but the short version is to prevent [rainbow tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table).  With a salt, you would have to create one rainbow table per salt.  In this example, the salt is twenty-two characters long.  Even if we limited salts to just decimal digits, that would be 10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 tables.  If we allow salts to be any base 64 digit, it's much bigger.  Salts don't need to be secret to prevent rainbow tables.