# How do BCryptPasswordEncoder check the passed plain password while using salt?

Tags: bcrypt, salt

I've check the source of BCryptPasswordEncoder and found it won't return generated random salt.  Then, while we check the plain password later, we don't know which salt did this user use at that time, so how can BCryptPasswordEncoder check whether plain password and encrypted password are the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [yii CPasswordHelper: hashPassword and verifyPassword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20394137/yii-cpasswordhelper-hashpassword-and-verifypassword)

Comment: thank you , that's the answer