# Explanation of salt in bcypt

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt

```
bcrypt.hash(password,12, function(err, hash) {});
```

Please explain about hash value.
(e.g  why we use 12 or 8 or 16 pass the value )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are Salt Rounds and how are Salts stored in Bcrypt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46693430/what-are-salt-rounds-and-how-are-salts-stored-in-bcrypt)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you’re wondering what the **10** (that’s used for hashing) is, then that’s the work factor or the **number of rounds** the data is processed for. More rounds leads to more secured hash but slower/expensive process.

As more salt are:

```
rounds=8 : ~40 hashes/sec
rounds=9 : ~20 hashes/sec
rounds=10: ~10 hashes/sec
rounds=11: ~5  hashes/sec
rounds=12: 2-3 hashes/sec
```

for more information visit on: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt