# Does saltRounds improve security?

Tags: hash, passwords, bcrypt, salt, password-hash

I had to hash my password, for that i used bcrypt.
By following a tutorial, i found this code :

```
const saltRounds = 10;
    bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds).then(hashedPassword => {
    //...
}
```

I googled what is `saltRound` and what's its propos, till i found here
[What are Salt Rounds and how are Salts stored in Bcrypt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46693430/what-are-salt-rounds-and-how-are-salts-stored-in-bcrypt) that you can control the time it takes to hash your passwords.

Does this mean you can control the strength of crypted passwords with just one property `saltRounds` ?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that. The more rounds the better, but you can't magically transform a weak password into a strong one by increasing the number of rounds.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk but the accepted answer says (the higher the cost factor, the more hashing rounds are done. Increasing the cost factor by 1 doubles the necessary time. The more time is necessary, the more difficult is brute-forcing.) which means the more rounds, the more difficult is brute-forcing, the better security as a result. Am i wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, more work for bcrypt does indeed increase password security. The whole purpose of increasing work factors is to provide that increase.

Higher bcrypt work factors improve password security at  *the individual user level*, because it's harder to crack each user's hash individually (if the attacker is interested in just one specific account). No hash / factors will protect an extremely weak password, but stronger hashing has a better chance of extending protection "downward" through a weaker / intermediate range of password strengths.

Stronger work factors also increase password security at the *aggregate* security level (for the entire target user set). This is because higher bcrypt work factors make attacking *the entire set at once* materially harder - especially as the number of users grows. The more compute / cores / memory are required, the more expensive (in time and resources) it is for the attacker.

The trade-off, of course, is that more work for the attacker (harder to crack) also means more work for the defender / maintainer (higher resource cost for valid authentications). It's important to tune your work factor to be the highest that both you and your users can tolerate, including worst-case scenarios like an "authentication storm" (where all of your users need to re-authenticate simultaneously). A bcrypt cost of 12, and a target per-user delay of .5 seconds, is often a good balance of these factors - but you need to assess (and test!) this for your own use case.

Bonus advice: make sure that your library and supporting code can support **multiple costs simultaneously**. As hardware gets faster, you'll want to increase your work factor for new/reset passwords, while simultaneously supporting existing ones. Fortunately, most libraries handle this transparently - but again, test for your own use case.