# What ways are there to create unique salts for every user?

Tags: security, passwords, unique, password-protection, salt

I'm trying to store passwords which each have their own unique salts.

But I don't really get the whole concept of creating unique salts because I can't imagen 
**A.** How you would be able to create a unique salt for every user that creates an account,
**B.**  How you would be able to compare passwords since the salts differ from user to user.

So my questions are:

1. How can I make a unique salt for every user.
2. How would I be able to compare the password.

Answer (score 0):

Salts are generated with the help of the random source of the operating system `/dev/urandom`. This random number generator collects random events like user login, or hardware properties, to generate real randomness.

You need to store the salt together with the password hash, a common format is shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20399775/575765). To verify the password, one has to extract the stored salt and use them to build a comparable hash.