# Can We Create a matching Hash From a Bcrypt Password Hash?

Tags: encryption, hash, cryptography, bcrypt, libcrypto

I have made many research but I could not figure out if we have a BCrypt Hash for example this hash :
`$2a$12$XPC20niJIhZPxaKvJkSUfO/rwIetoScCze.tOcVS/aJzowvjpCPlq`

can I create or generate a **matching** hash for this one.

Comment: Yes, using the same password and the same salt you'll get the same hash.

Comment: so without knowing the password and the tow hash generated with the same password but different salt I can not compare them!

Comment: @AymenB'm - This is why the salt is part of the password-hash string, it can be extracted from there for comparison, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20399775/575765). Most password-hash libraries provide a function similar to `passwordVerify()` which does the comparison for you.